# Why is Javascript adding 1 then subtracting, or subtracting 1 then adding?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create a little Javascript program that adds 1 when I click a "+" button, and subtracts 1 when I click a "-" button. It works, however when I add 1 then goto subtract one, the first click of the "-" button will add one more, before subtracting.

Eg. 1, 2, 3, 4, (then I click the "-" button) 5, 4, 3...

```js
   var number = 1;
```

```html
<button type="button" onClick="document.getElementById('number').innerHTML = number++">+</button>
<button type="button" onClick="document.getElementById('number').innerHTML = number--">-</button>
<div id="number"></div>
```

Comment: `number++` returns the number, THEN increments it.  `++number` increments the number THEN returns it.

Comment: `number++` is being used as the post-increment operator. It returns the current value of the variable and _then_ increments the variable. You should be using the pre-increment version `++number`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

that is basically because you are doing `number++` and you should do `++number`.

```js
var number = 0;
```

```html
<button type="button" onClick="document.getElementById('number').innerHTML = ++number">+</button>
<button type="button" onClick="document.getElementById('number').innerHTML = --number">-</button>
<div id="number"></div>
```

to understand what happens [you need to know the following](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Increment_());

`a++` will return `a` and then do the `++` operation.

`++a` will return the result of doing the `++` operation over `a`.

```js
var a = 5;
var b = 8;

console.log(a++) // will show 5.
console.log(a) // will show 6, because the ++ operation was executed.

console.log(++b) //will show 9. because the ++ operation was executed.
console.log(b) // will keep showing 9.
```

Comment: @cale_b explained :)

Comment: Oh! that makes sense. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

++number will increment the value of number, and then return the incremented value.

```js
var number=1;
```

```html
<button type="button" onClick="document.getElementById('number').innerHTML = ++number">+</button>
<button type="button" onClick="document.getElementById('number').innerHTML = --number">-</button>
<div id="number"></div>
```

number++ will increment the value of number, but return the original value that i held before being incremented.

```js
var number =1;
```

```html
<button type="button" onClick="document.getElementById('number').innerHTML = number++">+</button>
<button type="button" onClick="document.getElementById('number').innerHTML = number--">-</button>
<div id="number"></div>
```